# SuiteCrm Rest API: JSON Body attributes throws error when calling POST or PUT

Tags: rest, suitecrm

I'm using postman in order to call SuiteCRM REST API.

I tried to call this endpoint

```
PATCH http://{{suitecrm-url}}/Api/V8/module
```

and i've added this payload to the body (Content-Type: Application/Json):

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "Accounts",
    "id": "3a3ae651-d509-2508-7dc4-5be2e51cc96b",
    "attributes": {
        "name": "name with space"
    }
  }
}
```

When the request is executed SuiteCRM gives this response:

```
{
  "errors": {
    "status": 400,
    "title": null,
    "detail": "The option \"attributes\" with value array is invalid."
  }
}
```

I found out that the problem was the whitespace in the value: when i tried to use the value "namewithspace", it worked.

Anyone has any idea how to solve this problem ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out this issue on github that resolved my problem:

https://github.com/salesagility/SuiteCRM/issues/6452

In short to make it work i had to modify the file in

```
/Api/V8/Params/Options/Fields.php
```

and replace this line

```
const REGEX_FIELD_PATTERN = '/[^\w-,]/';
```

with

```
const REGEX_FIELD_PATTERN = '/[^\w-,\s\]/';
```

The person mentioned in github:

> this is just for temporary fix and not upgrade safe

Comment: I wonder if there is some type of formatting one could use in the call to solve the problem in an (annoying) but upgrade safe way.